# g++ can't locate header files while CMake compilation is successful

Tags: c++, cmake

I've a project structure like this:

```
project root
│   CMakeLists.txt
│
└───common-libs
│   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   │   libFiles.cpp
│   │   libFiles.h
│   │   ...
│   
└───src
│   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   │   main.h
│   │   main.cpp
```

---

common-libs folder contains my own implementations of some functions. I can include them in `main.h` with `#include <libFiles.h>` without any problem. Cmake compiles it. Problem occured whenver I try to debug the main.cpp on Visual Studio Code. Normally I have a `task.json` file something like this:

```
{
  "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
  "args": [
        "-std=c++17",
        "-g",
        "-I",
        "${workspaceFolder}/common-lib/*.cpp",
        "${workspaceFolder}/common-lib/*.h",
        "-o",
        "main",
        "-lpthread"
        ...
        ]
}
```

There was a older version of the project where where I included the libraries with their relative path like so: `#include "../common-libs/libFiles.h"` and with task.json above I could debug without a problem. At that time there was no CMake in the project. While adding CMake I wanted to decouple the common-lib.

#### Problem

As I said, this code compiles with CMake. Although I give include directories on arguments to g++, whenever I try to run this on debug on VS Code, compiler seems to not see the files. Saying `no such file or directory`.

My assumption is since I'm not using any path -relative or not- and calling `#include <someFile.h>` like this, does compiler looks at just default directories and tries to find that file in those directories (in this case just default headers)? I either need to change the way I include header files, or I need to show the compiler where it can find the files.

What can I do to solve this?

---

If needed:

CMakeLists.txt on common-lib is something like this:

```
add_library(common-lib STATIC libFiles.cpp ...) # in reality there are more files of course

target_link_libraries(common-lib pthread curl ... )

target_include_directories(common-lib PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})
```

and CMakeLists.txt on src:

```
add_executable(main main.h main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE common-lib)
```

Comment: `-I` takes a directory, not a list of files.

Comment: `"${workspaceFolder}/common-lib/*.h",`  Should not be in the args. The `-I` should be `-Ifolder` where folder is your include directory.

Comment: `What can I do to solve this?` Use CMakeTools in VSCode instead of editing your `tasks.json`

Comment: Using CMakeTools solved. Thanks

Comment: Also another thanks for pointing out how I use -I wrongly.

Comment: Or you can replace your build command with `cmake --build BUILDDIR`